# Both csv file are identical yet I get mismatch error in my python code output

Tags: python

I have written a script which basically compares two excel file and return mismatch error when it happens.

So, below is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
def main():
    sheet1 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = '1.csv')
    sheet2 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = '2.csv')
    # Iterating the Columns Names of both Sheets
    for i,j in zip(sheet1,sheet2):

        # Creating empty lists to append the columns values
        a,b =[],[]

        # Iterating the columns values
        for m, n in zip(sheet1[i],sheet2[j]):

            # Appending values in lists
            a.append(m)
            b.append(n)

        # Sorting the lists
        a.sort()
        b.sort()

        # Iterating the list's values and comparing them
        for m, n in zip(range(len(a)), range(len(b))):
            if a[m] != b[n]:
                print('Column name : \'{}\' and Row Number : {}'.format(i,m))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My output is:

```
Column name : 'PL' and Row Number : 0
Column name : 'PL' and Row Number : 1
Column name : 'PL' and Row Number : 2
```

FYI: in both excel file, PL column contains 'null' value, still it throws the mismatch error.

Can anyone help me to pinpoint how to debug?

Comment: Try changing `sheet2` to `pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = '1.csv')`. This way you know if there is something wrong in the code or something wring with the files.

Comment: @JhanzaibHumayun  I did that, still same output, it seems error is with code.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check that both values are not `np.nan` as well:

```
if a[m] != b[n] and (a[m] is not np.nan or b[n] is not np.nan):
    print('Column name : \'{}\' and Row Number : {}'.format(i,m))
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but `b[n] in not None` is not valid syntax, and pandas likely sees `a[m]` and `b[n]` as `np.nan` rather than `None`. That would be why `a[m] != b[n]`, because NaN isn't equal to itself.

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue, I changed null values to some number in both files, I don't get any error which means, files match, but changing it to null (as they were) creates problem which means, my code can't check for null values it seems?

Comment: @AyushChhangani, can you check what the type of the cell is? Put `print(type(a[m]))` before the if statement. They might be of some other type and not `np.nan`.

Comment: They are either <class 'str'> or <class 'int'> or <class 'float'>

Comment: Is there any other insights on same?

Comment: @AyushChhangani what is the type of the cells that have the `null` value. `!=` should work fine for string, int and floats, but the problem might be that the cells that are empty contain a space or two, which can lead to them not being equal. In case all your cells are ints or floats, and the empty cells contain some spaces then you can add the condition that if `type(b[n]) == str and type(a[n]) == str` then both are equal.

Comment: cells are not empty rather than they have value as 'null'. When I changed those to 123, code was working fine, however, the type of a[m] for the null value column is strangely <class 'int'>, not sure why. I can share u my excel file if u wish.

Comment: @AyushChhangani then print out the value of that int

Comment: Well, issue has been resolved. I got what I wanted from comparison. Thanks for all help. Road of dev is filled with such obstacles :D

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check this out: [Pandas DataFrame Compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html)

It will tell you where differences are, between two DFs.

A small example :

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = { "key":[1,2,3,4,5], "key2":[5,6,7,8,9]}
d2 = { "key": [1,2,3,4,6], "key2":[5,6,7,8,10]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df1.compare(df2)
```

will output a dataframe with a multi-column index like follows

```sh
   key       key2
  self other self other
4  5.0   6.0  9.0  10.0
```

However, this only works for DFs with same labels (or column names).
If the column names are not exactly the same you can do `df[["key","key1"]].compare(df2[["key","key1"]])` in order to select the matching columns)